# Issue with nvm and installation of node

Tags: node.js, nvm

I want to install node 4.8.7 on ubuntu 18.04.

I do `nvm install node 4.8.7` and I get this error :

```
curl: (56)GnuTLS recv error (-24): Decryption has failed.
BInary download from https://nodejs.org/dist/v10.11.0/node-v10.11.0.tar.xz failed.
```

Any idea of where this idea could come from?

Comment: try `nvm install 4.8.7`.

Comment: nvm -ls remote   - what u get    ref : www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-16-04